# Ensuring index is used on Informix DATETIME column

Tags: database, datetime, indexing, informix

Say I have a table on an Informix DB:

```
create table password_audit (
    username CHAR(20),
    old_password CHAR(20),
    new_password CHAR(20),
    update_date DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION));
```

I need the update_date field to be in milliseconds (or seconds maybe - same question applies) because there will be multiple updates of the password on the same day.

Say, I have a nightly batch job that wants to retrieve all records from the password_audit table for today.

To increase performance, I want to put an index on the update_date column. If I do this:

```
CREATE INDEX pw_idx ON password_audit(update_date);
```

and run this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM password_audit
WHERE DATE(update_date) = mdy(?,?,?)
```

(where ?, ?, ? are the month, day and year passed in by my batch job)

then I don't think my index will be used - **is that right?**

I think I need to create an index something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX pw_idx ON password_audit(DATE(update_date));
```

- **is that right?**

Answer (score 1):

Because you are forcing the server to convert two values to DATE, not DATETIME, then it probably won't use an index.

You would do best to generate the SQL as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM password_audit
 WHERE update_date
       BETWEEN DATETIME(2010-08-02 00:00:00.00000) YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
           AND DATETIME(2010-08-02 23:59:59.99999) YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
```

That's rather verbose.  Alternatively, and maybe slightly more easily:

```
SELECT *
  FROM password_audit
 WHERE update_date >= DATETIME(2010-08-02 00:00:00.00000) YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
   AND update_date <  DATETIME(2010-08-03 00:00:00.00000) YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
```

Both of these should be able to use the index on the update_date column.  You can experiment with dropping some of the trailing zeroes from the literals, but I don't think you'll be able to remove them all - but see what the SET EXPLAIN ON output tells you.

Depending on your server version, you might need to run UPDATE STATISTICS after creating the index before the optimizer uses it at all; that is more of a problem on older (say 10.00 and earlier) versions of Informix than on the current (11.10 and later) versions.

Comment: OK, thanks Jonathan, will look into this. You don't think the second index I proposed would be used by the SQL I proposed?

Comment: @dairemac: Jonathan's query examples imply that the index be only on update_date. Whenever you direct the engine to convert or cast a column in a query, it will scan the whole table to perform the conversion, thus not taking advantage of the index. See what EXPLAIN tells you.

Comment: The functional index could work...but it will store the function results.  If you don't have a regular (non-functional) index on on the column, then the functional index should work fine.

Comment: Never got a chance to set this up due to requirements changes. If I get a chance I'll do it for the sake of interest and post results back here. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. I Didn't see 'date_to_accounts_ni' defined in your password_audit table. 
   What datatype/length is it?
2. Your first index on password_audit.update_date is adequate, why would you want to index
   (DATE(update_table))?

Comment: 1. Sorry, should be update_date not date_to_accounts_ni. Have amended question.

2. Because the SQL that will be querying this table will be looking for all records with an update_date on a particular date i.e. WHERE DATE(update_date) = mdy(?,?,?)

Comment: If you are not interested in the time, you may want to use a separate date and time field and index on them separately.  This will make the retrieval of the date an exact match, whereas using date + time will almost never yield and exact match.